# Designing a database file format

Tags: c#, database, file, binary, format

I would like to design my own database engine for educational purposes, for the time being. Designing a binary file format is not hard nor the question, I've done it in the past, but while designing a database file format, I have come across a very important question:

How to handle the deletion of an item?

So far, I've thought of the following two options:

- Each item will have a "deleted" bit which is set to 1 upon deletion.

  - Pro: relatively fast.
  - Con: potentially sensitive data will remain in the file.
- `0x00` out the whole item upon deletion.

  - Pro: potentially sensitive data will be removed from the file.
  - Con: relatively slow.
- Recreating the whole database.

  - Pro: no empty blocks which makes the follow-up question void.
  - Con: it's a *really* good idea to overwrite the whole 4 GB database file because a user corrected a typo. I will sell this method to Twitter ASAP!

Now let's say you already have a few empty blocks in your database (deleted items). The follow-up question is how to handle the insertion of a new item?

- Append the item to the end of the file.

  - Pro: fastest possible.
  - Con: file will get huge because of all the empty blocks that remain because deleted items aren't actually deleted.
- Search for an empty block exactly the size of the one you're inserting.

  - Pro: may get rid of some blocks.
  - Con: you may end up scanning the whole file at each insert only to find out it's very unlikely to come across a perfectly fitting empty block.
- Find the first empty block which is equal or larger than the item you're inserting.

  - Pro: you probably won't end up scanning the whole file, as you will find an empty block somewhere mid-way; this will keep the file size relatively low.
  - Con: there will still be lots of leftover `0x00` bytes at the end of items which were inserted into bigger empty blocks than they are.

Rigth now, I think the first deletion method and the last insertion method are probably the "best" mix, but they would still have their own small issues. Alternatively, the first insertion method *and* scheduled full database recreation. (Probably not a good idea when working with really large databases. Also, each small update in that method will clone the whole item to the end of the file, thus accelerating file growth at a potentially insane rate.)

Unless there is a way of deleting/inserting blocks from/to the middle of the file in a file-system approved way, what's the best way to do this? More importantly, how do databases currently used in production usually handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not start by looking at how existing systems work?  If this is for your own education that will benefit you more in the long run.

Look at the tried and true [B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)/[B+Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B+_tree) for starters.  Then look at some others like Fractal Tree indexes, SSTables, Hash Tables, Merge Tables, etc.

Start by understanding how a 'database' stores and indexes data.  There are great open source and documented examples of this both in the NoSQL space as well as the more traditional RDBMS world.  Take apart something that exists, understand it, modify it, improve it.

I've been down this road, though not for educational purposes.  The .NET space lacked any thread-safe B+Tree that was disk-based, so I wrote one.  You can read some about it on my blog at http://csharptest.net/projects/bplustree/ or go download the source and take it apart: http://code.google.com/p/csharptest-net/downloads/list

Comment: Thanks for directing me to B-Tree and related algorithms. I had no knowledge of them. Time to study!

Answer (score 2):

the engines you name are very different... and your engine seems to have not so much in common with them... your engine sound similar to the good old dBase format...

For deletion the idea with the bit is good... make the part with overwriting deleted items with 0x00 configurable...

For Insertion you should keep a list of free blocks with their respective size... this list gets updated when you delete an item and when you grow the file and when you shrink the filt... this way you can determine very fast how to handle an insertion...

Comment: Keeping a list of empty blocks is indeed a good idea, but it brings back the same question. Unless I store it in a separate file, how to handle adding/removing indexes to/from the same file at the end/start. Probably one way is to allocate a few empty blocks at the start dedicated to this list? Or to write it to the very end, and when a new item is inserted, overwrite the index list, then write a new list to the end of the file, again. This last one doesn't seem like such a good idea though.

Comment: @RoliSoft some egines keep separate files, others store it at predefeined point in the file, i.e. at the start of every 4 MB block they have a list with 64 KB size that manages that block... when they need to grow they grow in steps of 4 MB and so on... the numbers are not relevant... you could choose any number you like but keep the scheme simple and clear...

Answer (score 1):

There are open source databases why dont you look at them first. MySQL source code can be a good start. You can download the [source](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads) and get into it.

Also, you can start investigating the data structures being used by databases, then look at persistence strategies and so forth.

Comment: I've thought of that, however the source of MySQL and similar open-source database engines are too complex for me to just search and study for the behavior I want to know. And I was unable to find any very primitive yet somewhat effective open-source engines.